# Google App Engine The requested URL / was not found on this server not always

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I created an Google App Engine project using Webapp2 everything was working well three days ago but today (now) surprised that it is misbehaving it sometimes saying

**The requested URL / was not found on this server**

then if I reload the url in the browser a number of times like 10 times. I can see my website.

It redirect the user to login in their Google Account then checks if the user is registered and give personalized content or an information. Trying reloading again in the browser it leads to

**The requested URL / was not found on this server**.

What is going on? Is it caused by the location chosen when making a Google Cloud Project, there was no Africa in the choices so I chose the nearby zone!

The [misbehaving url is this](http://cngiramicroloanscentre.appspot.com/) though it if it loads it may check if your email is registered first...

This is `app.yaml` file:

```
application: cngiramicroloanscentre
version: alpha
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:
- url: /
  script: cngira.app
  login: required
- url: /loanee/.*
  script: loanee.app
  login: required
- url: /officers
  script: officers.app
  login: required
- url: /loanees
  script: loanees.app
  login: required
- url: /loanees/.*
  script: loanees.app
  login: required
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
```

The part of code that route in `cngira.py` is:

```
....
app= webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)],debug=True)
```

The class MainPage is:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
"""docstring for MainPage"""
def get(self):
    user=users.get_current_user()
    user_email=user.email()
    fetched_user=(ndb.Key("Officer",user_email)).get()
    if(fetched_user==None and user_email != "johnnnoni@gmail.com" and user_email != "barakarichard1992@gmail.com"):
        self.response.out.write("Sorry you are not authorised to access this place yet consult the authorised to add you to add you!! "+user_email)
    else:
        template_in=template_env.get_template("templates/index.html")
        if(user_email=="johnnnoni@gmail.com" or user_email == "barakarichard1992@gmail.com"):
            dictionary_to_pass={"navigations":navigations}
            self.response.out.write(template_in.render(dictionary_to_pass))
        else:
            self.response.out.write(template_in.render( { "navigations":navigation_for_officer } ))
```

Comment: It's impossible to guess unless you show some code...

Comment: The issue is that I do not even know which code should I send? `app.yaml` or? because it works then it doesnt work then it works then it doesnt...Does it have something to do with code??

Comment: Show both 'app.yaml' and the handler for the '/' route.

Comment: I have added...@MihailRussu

Comment: You only added the route definition but not the route handler (the MainPage function).

Comment: I have added it, though I should say that the app works well in development server @MihailRussu

Comment: Also there might be a traceback that provides error info at python level  (the "requested url' is presumably at browser level, look at the logs for actual python output).

Comment: The logs are pretty long even for a single request and copy and paste never format them because they are in collapse and expand state. May be if you could tell me what exactly should I expand for a single request with 404 and send it? @Oliver

Comment: The 404 error page is filled in by GAE, not by your application. This typically indicates inability to locate (or start?) an instance of your application to pass the request to. What do you see in your app's [versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=cngiramicroloanscentre)?

Comment: Yeah this is definitely the reason since, the old way was when registering your application using console, even if you don't specify the location. So I deleted the project and make a new one, and specified the location. Now I everything is working as expected... @DanCornilescu

Comment: Hey Xenolion or @DanCornilescu  . You could post the solution to this issue as a separate answer so that other people who find this question immediately see that it's solved.

Comment: @Xenolion By "even if you don't specify the location" you mean you didn't have to specify a region?

Comment: @A.Queue Done, Thanks.

Comment: @Xenolion also please delete the emails and the project name. Even if they aren't real or were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The 404 page displayed in this case was not the typical one for a 404 error coming from the application, but the "broken robot",

> 404. That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

one provided by the Google infrastructure:

[image]

This is typically an indication that the GAE infrastructure was unable to determine from the request the proper application instance to start (if needed) and pass the request to for processing. The request didn't even reach the application code.

Usually that indicates some sort of application configuration problem or, in rare cases, an outage in the GAE/Google hosting infrastructure.

As OP's comments indicate, deleting the project and creating a new one instead fixed the problem in this instance. A rather radical approach - the project identifier can't be re-used, deleting the old project might not be considered acceptable in some cases.

But cloning the application config+code in a new (temporary) project just to double-check is always something to try - if the new project works as expected contacting Google's support is probably needed to repair the old project.